# fatal error: linux/nvme.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux

Im coding a small tool which performs some operations on nvme drives including passtrough command etc. Therefore I want to use <linux/nvme.h> since it offers some nice structs and defines.

When I try to compile I get following message

`fatal error: linux/nvme.h: No such file or directory`

So I have checked the default gcc inlcude Path `/usr/include/linux` and no nvme.h inside this folder.
Then I have searched in `/usr` for the file and indeed it exists, but only in linux-header directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -a)/include/linux`.

So the main question is: why is nvme.h not located in `/usr/include` and whats the correct way to use it?
After some research it looks like `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -a)/include/linux` is intended for kernel-modules only

I have tried to use `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -a)/include/linux` in my makefile but it ends in a mess during compilation. Anyways i think thats not the cleanest way to do it

btw: I am using kernel 5.15

Comment: /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -a)/include/linux is not for user space and suppose that would collide with /usr/include/linux which one is for user space. Idk, just for test try to copy only nvme.h in dir where building is going and add `-I.` to flags (supposing '#include "nvme.h"' in a source file). Or make copy of structs and macros (which needed) in some project header.

Comment: Actually this is what I have done. I have copied nvme.h to /usr/include and it works. But this does not feel right. I mean I will use it if there was a no “correct” way to do this